# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline on localhost with local script

Tags: javascript, html, macos, apache, firefox

I'm debugging a page locally in Apache on OSX and I'm getting these errors:

> Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/Cats.js”. Cats.html:8:1
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). Cats.html:1:1
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost/Cats.js (“script-src”). 2
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).

My application script is in the same directory as the page.

```
<script id="myScript" type="text/javascript" src="Cats.js"></script>
```

These don't happen when loading from `file://` protocol but are happening in `http://localhost/`.

Note: I haven't seen these errors before when testing locally. Are they new?

**Update:**
From what I can tell it might be a change in the settings in the built in Apache server but I can't find anything in the Apache configs. It may also be something Firefox wasn't enforcing but now is.

It looks like to solve it I have to add a content security meta tag to fix it or change some settings in the Apache server. But that's odd. I've never seen this before.

It loads fine in Chrome.